# Scaled up micro service data consistency issue

Tags: java, docker, spring-data-jpa, microservices

I have a micro service called account which is responsible to manage all the account information. I am running this service in a container and scaled to 3 replicas. Occasionally when i create the account and try to fetch it lets say from different service after creating the account(round robin) i am getting null back.

I am using Save instead of saveAndFlush. Will switching to save and flush will help ? or any other suggestions are welcome. Here is the code for the Account Repo. And it is consumed via a service layer and through rest api.

```
public interface AccountRepo extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {


Account findByRkPptIdAndPlanId(String rkParticipantID, Long plan);

Account findOne(Long id);


Account save(Account account);


Account findByPlanIdAndParticipantId(Long planId, Long participantId); }
```

Service layer using redis caching as well.

```
@Service
public class AccountService
{  
    @Override
    @Cacheable(value = "accountById", unless = "#result==null")
    public Account get(Long id) {

        Account found = accountRepo.findOne(id);
           return found;
    }

    @Override
    public Account add(Account item) throws DataException {
        item.setId(null);
        item = accountRepo.save(item);
        return item;
    }

    @Override
    @CacheEvict(value = "accountById", key = "#item.id")
    public Account update(Account item) throws DataException {
        item = accountRepo.saveAndFlush(item);
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's stopping you from trying? Without a good [mcve] and a better description of your architecture it's hard to tell. It's possible that your transaction boundaries are incorrect - if your transaction only gets committed after the service's output has been sent back to the client, you may end up with a race condition like you describe. The transaction should be committed at the end of your createAccount service method.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I have updated the issue. Any suggestion can be helpful